# How to vertically center dynamically 1 or 2 lines of text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Please note the attached image/wireframe. How can I build this element with CSS. Where if there is one line of text it is vertically centered but also support 2 lines also being vertically centered?

[image]

Comment: Is the circle on the right always the same size?

Comment: Treating your divs as table cells is the best way to do this. Take a look at this article: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Comment: where is your tried fiddle /

Comment: Circle is always the same size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making your wrapper div `display:table:` and your inner text div `display:table-cell`. See example below:

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        One Line</br>
        Two Line</br>
        Three Line</br>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
width:400px;
height:200px;
display:table;
background:brown;
}

.inner{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
text-align:center;
}
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/pgwL47oy/1/

Answer (score 2):

This is already mentioned in a comment on your question, but usually the usage of `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;` is what you're after.

The idea is to get the parent container to be displayed as a table with `display: table;`, and then the span or paragraph element you're using to contain those text nodes is given the above `table-cell` display with `vertical-align`.

It's worked for me before, should be worth a shot!

[Here's a CSS Tricks article that could help you out further](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

Hope that helps! :)